# Build dynamic where condition firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The default query method is complicated. I was trying to create a wrapper around it which attaches where clauses based on the fields passed to it.

```
import { collection, getDocs, getFirestore, query, conditions } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore();

export const getDocuments = async ({ collectionName, whereConditions = {}, fetchSingle = false }) => {
  const whereQuery = Object.entries((whereConditions)).map(([key, value]) => where(key, "==", value));
  const q = query(collection(db, collectionName), ...whereQuery)
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const result = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    result.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
  });
  return fetchSingle ? result[0] : result;
}
```

But it returns `[]` array in each case. It seems `where()` is not being applied.

Update:

When I log `queryWhere` this is what I get.

```
[
    {
        "hc": {
            "segments": [
                "id"
            ],
            "offset": 0,
            "len": 1
        },
        "lc": "==",
        "fc": "EQdg5wDPFYCEqhImRznD",
        "type": "where"
    }
]
```

When I log `whereConditions` this is what I get,

```
{
    "id": "EQdg5wDPFYCEqhImRznD"
}
```

I tried many combination. It is working when I pass other filters than `id`.

It doesn't return result when `id` is passed in where.

Comment: Can you `console.log(where)` (conditions as per updated code) and share a screenshot of the output? I doubt this `Object.entries((where)).map(([key, value])`, Isn't `where` param an object by default? `[key, value]` means all items in `where` array are arrays..

Comment: I dont't think that's the issue. I updated the code also added the resopsne.

Comment: Can you log the `whereConditions` and share that... it might be easier to try replicating that issue then.. Apart form that code look correct.

Comment: I have updated the description.

Comment: Firestore documentation and api really sucks. Document doesn't have id field in it so  it can't be queried?

Comment: For document ID, you'll have to use documentId() as field. Iirc `__name__` as field name works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your query is looking for "id" field in the document. If you want to query based on document ID then try this:

```
import { documentId } from "firebase/firestore"

const qConstraint = where(documentId(), "==", "DOC_ID")
```